# Where should I ask a question about certifications?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about Microsoft Certifications. What is the best Stack Exchange site to ask that question on?

The question was about MCTS, whether it is an accumulation of tests (like MCSD) or if each test is stand alone.

Comment: Can you give a sample question?

Comment: Related (on Meta Programmers): [Why do certification questions keep getting closed?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6442/25936)

Comment: The question was about MCTS, whether it is an accumulation of tests (like MCSD) or if each test is stand alone. I got a lot of downvotes when I posted to Programmers, so I came here to find a better place to ask the question. I don't understand why asking site recommendations in the meta site get downvotes. If we aren't supposed to ask here, where are we supposed to ask?

Comment: @Yannis worth noting that MSO doesn't favor these either: [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/839601)

Comment: Ignore the downvotes, you did the right thing by asking here. Meta voting is a bizarre beast, it doesn't always make sense...

Comment: Some people vote down site recommendation posts about questions that would be too broad, primarily opinion-based etc. (that would render them off-topic in all of the SE network) It's a flawed bias, but you can't *not* let people express their opinions.

Comment: Just for the record: the initial question was bad. It had nothing to go on. Now it is answerable. That is why I retracted my lose and down vote.

Answer (score 6):

There's not really a good site for this.

You should probably ask on Microsoft's site.

Answer (score 6):

Questions about Certifications are usually off-topic. Asking about how the exams are like, how useful it is, etc. are all considered primarily opinion based or too broad. Asking where to get those, or where to follow courses can be seen as recommendations... off-topic too.

If you have a question about a specific question from an exam or certification, it might be on-topic on Stack Overflow if it is programming-related.

Your specific question doesn't fit in any site at the moment. Try to contact Microsoft or a partner and see if they can help.